# Where an how can i put rename file

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to write code so as to rename files if a file with the same name has already been uploaded. For example if you upload "internet.jpg"  but this file already exists in server side and bd, then the system renames to "internet_2.jpg"

My code:

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("view") or die(mysql_error()) ;

if ($_FILES["imagen"]["error"] > 0){
  echo "ha ocurrido un error";
} else {

  $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
  $limite_kb = 100;

  if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

    $ruta = "./image/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];

      $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);   
      if ($resultado){
        $nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];

        @mysql_query("UPDATE product SET  image='data/$nombre' Where id=55")  ;

        echo "la imagen ha sido actualizada exitosamente";
        echo "

    ";
      } else {
        echo "ocurrio un error al mover el archivo.";
      }

  } else {
    echo "archivo no permitido, es tipo de archivo prohibido o excede el tamano de $limite_kb Kilobytes";
  }
}

?>
```

----------------------Thanks-----------------------------

```
thank you very much Farhan Ihsas, your code worked perfect!
 I just change two lines

$new_name =     $rand . '_'.   $dotName ;

and

@mysql_query("UPDATE product SET  image='./image/$new_name' Where product_id=55")  ;


Thanks for such a quick response!

thank you both ( Farhan Ihsas and Kieran )
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Any errors? Please, [edit] the Question and add more details to it. @YoungStudent, aquí se habla en Inglés, rules of the house ;)

Comment: before you move the uploaded file just check for its existance with [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) if you would like to iterate, like you wrote, should use [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for files checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you haven't any error on your code, so find out the line and replace it..

```
if(in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'],$permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size'] <=$limite_kb * 1024){

$fileName = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$ruta = "./image/" . $fileName ;
if (file_exists($ruta)) {

$dotType = pathinfo( $fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$rand = rand(111, 2333);
$dotName = str_replace('.' . $dotType, '', $fileName) ;
$new_name = $dotName . '_' .  $rand . '.'.  $dotType ;

$ruta = "./image/" . $new_name;
} 
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
```

Comment: thank you very much Farhan Ihsas, your code worked perfect!
 I just change two lines
  
$new_name =     $rand . '_'.   $dotName ;

and

@mysql_query("UPDATE product SET  image='./image/$new_name' Where product_id=55")  ;
  

Thanks for such a quick response!
  
thank you both ( Farhan Ihsas and Kieran )

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a combination of [file_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

E.g.

```
function setFilename($file, $count = 1) {
   if (file_exists($file)) {
       return setFilename($file, $count++);
   } else {
       $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
       move_uploaded_file($file, "{$fileData['dirname']}/{$path_parts['filename']}_{$count}.{$path_parts['extension']}";  
   }
}
```